# Marketingcloud Rest api payload

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Marketing Cloud Rest api developer guide says to keep the payload not greater than 4 megabytes.
Do you know how to check it?

Is it enough saving the rest api call i developed into a file of my computer and See the size of the file?

Thanks
Emanuela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe. There's some discrepancy between definitions of sizes. Salesforce tends to use the SI megabyte, which is different than the traditional mebibyte. The difference is 194,304 bytes. Windows uses mebibyte, which was traditionally called megabyte before the SI standardization, which is 1,048,576 bytes, while a modern megabyte is 1,000,000 bytes. So, depending on who you ask, 4 MB is 4,194,304 bytes or 4,000,000 bytes. If you're using a Windows system, you'll probably see mebibytes, meaning the maximum file size is 3.814 MB (rounded down), but on other systems may be represented as a maximum of 4.00 MB. As long as your request does not exceed 3.814 MB, you should definitely be safe, but be sure to check the actual number of *bytes* of the file, not the MB abbreviation.

Comment: Superthanks @sfdcfox